# Jpanels inside JLayeredPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

I'm using JLayeredPanel to put two panels on top of each other. The first panel would act like a background and the second panel which uses JFileChooser to get the user's image to print on the panel then that panel will lay on top of the first panel with a button click.

I've sucessfully get the image to print onto the second panel fron JFileChooser but unable to get the second panel to lay on top of the first panel.

Here's the outline.
http://s8.postimg.org/ofblrk179/outline.png

Here's my code.
...

```
    public class DesignerUI extends JFrame {
    public DesignerUI() {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                DesignerUI frame = new DesignerUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
    card2 = new JPanel();
    cards.add(card2, "Design");
    card2.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnGraphic = new JButton("Add Graphic");
    btnGraphic.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 53);
    panel.add(btnGraphic);
    btnGraphic.addActionListener(new chooseGraphic());

    JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();
    lp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    lp.setBounds(400,0,382,406);
    card2.add(lp);

    panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 383, 406);

    picPanel = new JPanel();
    picPanel.setBounds(105, 115, 213, 200);

    lp.add(picPanel, new Integer(2)); 
    lp.add(panel_1, new Integer(3)); 

private class chooseGraphic implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame graphicInputWindow = new JFrame();
        new graphicInputWindow();
    }
}

public class graphicInputWindow extends JFrame {
    JButton button;
    JButton select;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel picPanel;
    Image image;

    public graphicInputWindow() {
        super("Select Your Image");
        setResizable(false);
        button = new JButton("Browse");
        button.setBounds(300, 300, 100, 40);
        select = new JButton("Select");
        select.setBounds(400, 300, 100, 40);
        picPanel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel();

        label.setBounds(10, 10, 670, 250);
        add(button);
        add(select);
        add(picPanel);
        add(label);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
                file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System
                        .getProperty("user.home")));

                // filter the files
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "*.Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
                file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);

                // if the user click on save
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
                    String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    label.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));

                }

                // if the user click on cancel
                else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("No File Select");

                }
            }
        });

        select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // if user click select
                JPanel picPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                picPanel.add(label);
                lp.add(picPanel);
                lp.setVisible(true);
                //close window returns to card2
                setVisible(false);

            }
        });

        setSize(700, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        revalidate();
        contentPane.revalidate();
        contentPane.repaint();
    }

    public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String ImagePath) {
        ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(ImagePath);
        Image img = MyImage.getImage();
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(panel_1.getWidth(),
                panel_1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        return image;
    }

    /*protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }*/
}
}
```

Comment: `JPanel` is opaque by default

Comment: Want to go back and fix your code example so it actually runs

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited in my entire code so the program should run. Just missing the clothes Templates and the Databases
Here's the Databases code:

public class Databases {
 ArrayList<BufferedImage> templateDatabase = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
 
 public void addImage( BufferedImage aFilename ){
  templateDatabase.add( aFilename );
 }

 public BufferedImage get(int i) {
  return templateDatabase.get(i);
 }
 
 public boolean isEmpty(int i){
  if(templateDatabase.size()>0){
   return false;
  }
  else{
   return true;
  } 
 }
}

Comment: Can you break it down to a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry. I updated the code and attached a image of an outline of what the code supposed to do. The problem I have is the jpanel from the second frame doesn't show up on top of the jpanel that already has the buffered image which both panels are inside jlayeredpane so that they can lay on top of each other.